# I need to enter an array of data in my database, the data is imported from a excel file

Tags: php, arrays, excel, cakephp

I am using [Excel Reader](https://code.google.com/p/php-excel-reader/) to import a excel file into my database. I am also using postgres and cakephp. Now I have problem for import the imformation to my DataBase, I'm trying to enter through a for.

message of error:

> Call to a member function create() on a non-object.

my controller.

```
<?php
App::import('Vendor', 'excel_reader2'); 
class SoyaproductorcomprasController extends AppController {
    public $components = array('Session','RequestHandler');
    public function logout() {
        $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
    }
    public function excel() {
    $this->loadModel('SoyaProductorCompra');
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $datos = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader();
            $datos->read($this->request->data['SoyaProductorCompra']['excel']['tmp_name']);
            for ($i = 1; $i <= $datos->sheets[0]['numRows']; $i++) {
                $this->SoyaProductorCompra->create();
                $this->request->data['SoyaProductorCompra']['user_id'] = $this->Auth->user('id');
                $this->request->data['SoyaProductorCompra']['campana'] = $datos->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][1];
                $this->request->data['SoyaProductorCompra']['nit'] = $datos->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][2];
                $this->request->data['SoyaProductorCompra']['proveedor'] = $datos->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][3];
                $this->request->data['SoyaProductorCompra']['regimengrano'] = $datos->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][4];
                $this->request->data['SoyaProductorCompra']['codigograno'] = $datos->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][5];
                $this->request->data['SoyaProductorCompra']['producto'] = $datos->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][6];
                $this->request->data['SoyaProductorCompra']['toneladas'] =$datos->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][7];
                $this->request->data['SoyaProductorCompra']['preciodolar'] = $datos->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][8];
                $this->request->data['SoyaProductorCompra']['total'] = $datos->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][9];
                $this->request->data['SoyaProductorCompra']['fecharegistro'] = $datos->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][10];
                $this->SoyaProductorCompra->save($this->data);
            }

        }
    }

}
?>
```

my view.

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('SoyaProductorCompra', array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'));?>
<?php

echo $this->Form->input('excel',array( 'type' => 'file', 'label'=>'Ingrese excel'));
echo $this->Form->end('Submit')
?>
```

Comment: `$this->SoyaProductorCompra->save($this->data)` !== `$this->SoyaProductorCompra->save($this->request->data)`

Comment: Sorry not found, but thanks.

Comment: So, what is the problem?

Comment: this is message. Call to a member function create() on a non-object. of the error

Comment: $this->loadModel('SoyaProductorCompra'); this is the solution thnak for his help

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, try calling `$this->SoyaProductorCompra->create();` just before `$this->SoyaProductorCompra->save($this->request->data);`